# How to write a window service that track the number of times a specific folder was Opened

Tags: c#, .net, service

I Hope that this is the Correct way of asking this question. first my problem is that i want to know that how many times a specific folder was opened from the time my windows service start's. I don't want to write a desktop application for this purpose because i want it to happen in the background and also later i may want to add some more functionality. So that is why i need to be it a windows service.

is there some kind of OS Event that i can handle during my code, i.e the event is fired when a user open's folder.
If this is not the correct method then please let me know some other method that can help.

Comment: Define "open". Do you mean open it in Windows Explorer, or any way of listing the directory's contents? What about code enumerating the files in the directories, or a commandline where `cd` or `dir` is executed to or in that directory, or an OpenFileDialog, do you want to detect those? What are you trying to do, can't you fix that with setting the proper permissions on the directory?

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks! Yes where ever the folder is opened inside windows OS.

Comment: Please answer my question about what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: ok ! let's say i have a folder with path "c:\myfolder" Now i want to know that how many times this folder was opened since the last boot of the windows operating system (whether from windows explorer or openfiledialog or anywhere). I have to do some other calculations on that number in my code.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible in C#.  You can be notified of changes within a directory and infer from that that the directory was opened--but there are many times when a directory is opened and nothing will be changed.  What you're describing is most like a File System Filter Driver.

From [What is a File System Filter Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557282%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A file system filter driver can filter I/O operations for one or more file systems or file system volumes. Depending on the nature of the driver, filter can mean log, observe, modify, or even prevent.

Writing a filter is relatively easy, considering there are templates that you can use to base your work from.  But, they do consist of *kernel-mode code* meaning they're not written with C# (they are typically written with C) and they *are drivers*.

for more details: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540382(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This is not very helpful.  At least mention [*auditing*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399), the OP stands a chance to make that work.

Comment: Using audit logs is problematic because these are often configured as part of an enterprise`s policy--which means you are likely unreliably able to change these settings.  Audit logs are also not that unreliable from a data standpoint.  They are contained within event logs which can be configured to use a fixed space and be a circular buffer--which means some data could be missed.

Comment: Hmm, you don't think that enterprises have a policy about custom file system drivers?

Comment: My experience has been that it's easier to install software that does something specific (be it drivers or whatever) than it is to change the way things are pushed as Windows policies.